# Why are my points not being plotted?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, coordinates

I am currently creating a graph that that analyzes the correlation of absorption and concentration (Beer's law). While creating the graph, I've ran into a few problems, and I am now stuck. My plots are not showing up within my graph. Is it due to placement error? If possible, I would like to leave the ticks, labels, and title in the same (or similar format). Sorry in advance for the sloppiness, trying to get the function down before I make it pretty. But anyways, here is the code:

```
#importing matplotlib to create a graph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



#ploting out the points while labeling the graph
plt.plot([1.95E-06, 9.75E-06, 1.95E-05, 9.75E-05, 1.95E-04, 9.75E-04, 1.95E-
03],[0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4])
plt.xticks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [str('1.95E-03'), str('9.75E-04'), 
str('1.95E-04'), str('9.75E-05'),str('1.95E-05'), str('9.75E-06'), 
str('1.95E-06')])
plt.title('Red')
plt.ylabel('Absorption')
plt.xlabel('Concentration')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You may now choose one of the answers to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) such that this question is marked as solved. If you haven't already done so, you may also want to have a look around the [tour] page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data has x values well below 0.01, while your ticks start at 1, so your data will be to the left of the plot. I would suggest using a logarithmic x axis, just like the example below. This will also fix the problem with the x values being of different orders of magnitude. Note that I also put the tick strings in reverse order, assuming that you mistakenly wrote them the other way round. If not, please just go ahead and re-reverse them!

```
#importing matplotlib to create a graph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = [1.95e-06, 9.75e-06, 1.95e-05, 9.75e-05, 1.95e-04, 9.75e-04, 1.95e-03]
#ploting out the points while labeling the graph
plt.semilogx(x ,[0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4])
plt.xticks(x, [str('1.95E-03'), str('9.75E-04'), str('1.95E-04'), str('9.75E-05'),str('1.95E-05'), str('9.75E-06'), str('1.95E-06')], rotation=45)
plt.title('Red')
plt.ylabel('Absorption')
plt.xlabel('Concentration')
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('points.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: Semilogarithmic plot]

Answer (score 2):

Your xticks are completely out of the range where your data lives. Remove the line which sets the xticks and your plot is fine

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1.95E-06, 9.75E-06, 1.95E-05, 9.75E-05, 1.95E-04, 9.75E-04, 1.95E-03],
         [0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4])
plt.title('Red')
plt.ylabel('Absorption')
plt.xlabel('Concentration')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to use your custom ticks, you need to set them in the data range, i.e. somewhere between 0 and 0.002 and not between 1 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `plt.xticks` should be x-coords (not tick indexes).